# Using cgdb for a ncurses c application

Tags: gdb, ncurses, cgdb

When I debug a ncurses appplication I usually do the following:

```
gdb --tty=/dev/ttys000 ...
```

This will then make the ncurses application to run in a different terminal than the one gdb runs in.

Recently I discovered cgdb and I very much like it. Unfortunately it does not seem 
to respect the --tty option.

Are there any other way of doing this? How do the cgdb people debug cgdb :) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `tty` command the same way as `--tty` option, either in gdb or in cgdb. See [Debugging Ncurses Programs](http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/07-Debugging_Ncurses_Programs.php). Also you can use gdb in tui mode. It is much like cgdb.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Astonishingly this does not work on my machine. I asked in the cgdb IRC and there they told me to just attach the process and this turned out to be working. The only problem is that I can't reach any part of the code as I am attaching to a already running process....

Comment: I have tried this `(gdb) tty /dev/ttys000` on my machine on sample ncurses app and this worked for me. If this does not work on your machine than I don't know what is the problem, sorry. You may use gdb tui as I said, than `gdb --tty=/dev/ttys000` will also work.

Comment: I'm on os x 10.7 and gdb is not compiled with TUI... Entering tty works, what does not work is starting cgdb with the --tty=... option. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does entering tty work in cgdb via `tty` command? If it does, why not to use it? It is essentially the same as `--tty=...`,  [gdb doc](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Input_002fOutput).

Comment: Yeah it works. I have become tired of starting a terminal, entering sleep n, then looking for the tty, starting cgdb and entering it all manually. I wanted to write a shell script to do this for me which seems to be unbelievably complex....